# How to hold an image for every array

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to set image for every array in the UITabelView. How can I set image for every array from the photo library? So I can view it in the cell of the UITableView.

I hope this help this is my simple code [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iicqjlipn2mg3es/NewSavaData-2.zip)

Thanks from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do you mean for every image? You would do this with one array, populated with images.

You would do this in your table views `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, by telling the table view its cells image property will be filled with the object in the array at the index of the cell, e.g:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Thanks NSPostWhendle, what I am trying is to put a picture for every user in the UITableView which is pushed from array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
NSArray *photos = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                        nil] retain]; // Arrange images in the same order your table data is arranged.
```

Now, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
cell.imageView.image = [photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks OhhMee, But the user will only select one picture from the library. I may misunderstood.